# retain white spaces in fields when using awk

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, text-processing

I am using `nawk` on a pipe delimited file to print fields as index and key where some of the fields contain white space, when there is no white space everything works normal, but in case of white spaces somehow `awk` treats it as field separator and prints this o/p to new line. See my input below :

Input:

```
a|b|c d e|1|2|3
a|b c|d|1|2|2 3
```

Output:

```
Index=a|b|c 
Key=1|2|3
Index=d
Key=<null>
Index=e
Key=<null>
Index=a|b
Key=1|2|2
Index=c|d
Key=3
```

Expected Output:

```
Index=a|b|c d e
Key=1|2|3
Index=a|b c|d
Key=1|2|2 3
```

In short for two record 2 Index and 2 keys and keep the basic white spaces as it is.

I have to use below set of code for working on each line because there are too many fields and having huge data

```
    index=`echo "$line" | nawk -F '|' '
    function select_from(from,to,delim)
    {
            if (to < from) { return; };
            for (i=from;i<=to;i++)
            {
                            if (NF < i) { break;};
                            if (i < to)
                            {
                                    printf("%s%s",i,delim);
                            } else {
                                    printf("%s",i);
                            };
            };
    }
    {select_from(11,48,"|");};'`
```

response are correct when using some special character instead of space, but that is not correct on input data. so want to know if I can preserve space in this process.

Comment: so you are using `|` as a field separator despite it being a string you can find in any of the fields? This looks like a very bad way to maintain a file and will lead to major problems. May be better to use a CSV parser, enclose the fields in double quotes and make things easier.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

`from=1; to=3; delimiter="|"; awk -F"$delimiter" -v from="$from" -v to="$to" '!/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {printf "Index="; for(i=from; i<=to; i++) {printf $i; if(i<to) {printf "|"};} printf "\n"; printf "Key="; for(i=to+1; i<=NF; i++) {printf $i; if(i<NF) {printf "|"};} printf "\n"}' foo`

More readable

```
from=1; to=3; delimiter="|";
awk -F"$delimiter" -v from="$from" -v to="$to" '!/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {
    printf "Index=";
    for(i=from; i<=to; i++) {
        printf $i;
        if(i<to) {
            printf "|"
        };
    }
    printf "\n";
    printf "Key=";
    for(i=to+1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf $i;
        if(i<NF) {
            printf "|"
        };
    }
    printf "\n"
}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
a|b|c d e|1|2|3
a|b c|d|1|2|2 3

$ from=1; to=3; delimiter="|"; awk -F"$delimiter" -v from="$from" -v to="$to" '!/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {printf "Index="; for(i=from; i<=to; i++) {printf $i; if(i<to) {printf "|"};} printf "\n"; printf "Key="; for(i=to+1; i<=NF; i++) {printf $i; if(i<NF) {printf "|"};} printf "\n"}' foo
Index=a|b|c d e
Key=1|2|3
Index=a|b c|d
Key=1|2|2 3
```

Comment: `\s` matches an `s` in nawk. Use the standard `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` instead of the perl-isms. As far as I know, only GNU awk treats `\s` as whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `perl` command to get the expected output:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "Index=$1\nKey=$2\n" if /(.*?)[\s\|]([\|\d ]+)/' my_file
Index=a|b|c d e
Key=1|2|3
Index=a|b c|d
Key=1|2|2 3
```

I'd not use `[nmg]awk` for that task. Since your main script seems to be written in `bash`, just replace your `nawk` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -ne 'print "Index=$1\nKey=$2\n" if /(.*?)[\s\|]([\|\d ]+)/' my_file
```

Note that you can also remove the loop creating `$line` in your original script.

Comment: can I add it within awk function

Comment: @leArned: See my update

Answer (score 0):

Create a file and save the `awk` script bellow into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="|";} 
{ 
  printf"Index:";
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
       if ($i~/[[:alpha:]]/ && $(i+1)!~/[[:digit:]]/) { printf $i"|";
    }
    else if ($i~/[[:alpha:]]/ && $(i+1)~/[[:digit:]]/) {
    print $i
    }
  }

printf "\n"
} 


{ 
  printf"Key=:";
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
     if ($i~/[[:digit:]]/ && $(i+1)~/[[:digit:]]/) printf $i"|" ;
    else if ($i~/[[:digit:]]$/)  printf $i;

    }
printf "\n"
}
```

Save the file, run `sudo chmod +x awk-script-name.awk`, and run it with the test file like so:

```
$ cat testfile.txt                                                                                                                    
a|b|c d e|1|2|3
a|b c|d|1|2|2 3

$ key-index-script.awk testfile.txt                                                                                                   
Index:a|b|c d e

Key=:1|2|3
Index:a|b c|d

Key=:1|2|2 3
```